# concatenate values to hidden variable

Tags: c#, javascript

How to concatenate values to the  hdnfield value with comma on checkbox click event. when i click the checkbox i select order and passit to the JS function. If i select three checkboxes the hdnfield value should be like 1, 2, 3... something like that... how to do that?

```
if (chkBoxOne != null) 
{
    chkBoxOne.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return SelectOne('" + chkBoxOne.ClientID + "','" + e.Row.ClientID + "','" + lblorderId.Text + "')");
    //if (chkBoxOne.Checked)
    //    hdSelectAllOrderId.Value += ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblorderId")).Text + ",";
}


function SelectOne(id, rowID, OrderID) {
  var AllOrderIDs = 0;
  AllOrderIDs = Number(document.getElementById('ctl00_PagePlaceholder_hdSelectAllOrderId').value);
  alert(AllOrderIDs);
  if (document.getElementById(id).checked == true) {
      if (AllOrderIDs == '')
          AllOrderIDs = OrderID;
      else
          AllOrderIDs = AllOrderIDs + ' ,' + OrderID;
}
alert(AllOrderIDs);}
```

The above code is not working. when  i click on the firt checkbox its showing frist ordid, but when i click on the second one its not showing first ordid which is i already assigned to it. Its just showing second one...

```
   var AllOrderIDs = 0;
AllOrderIDs = document.getElementById('ctl00_PagePlaceholder_hdSelectAllOrderId').value;
var IDs = AllOrderIDs.split(',');
if (document.getElementById(id).checked == true) {
    if (IDs.indexOf(OrderID) == -1) {
        IDs.push(OrderID);
    }
}
else {
    var index = IDs.indexOf(OrderID);
    if (index != -1) {
        IDs = IDs.slice(index, 1);
    }
}
AllOrderIDs = IDs.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, yes, you forgot to save the value to hidden field.
Second, you are only handling the situation, when the checkbox state changes to "checked". thus, you don't delete IDs from hidden field. If you check-uncheck-and-check-again, you will have duplicate ID saved.
I recommend you to split your string into array of IDs and then work with it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Select(sender, OrderID)
{
    var AllOrderIDs = document.getElementById('hf1').value;
    var IDs = AllOrderIDs.split(',');
    if (sender.checked == true)
    {
        if (IDs.indexOf(OrderID.toString()) == -1)
        {
            IDs.push(OrderID);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var index = IDs.indexOf(OrderID.toString());
        if (index != -1)
        {
            IDs.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    AllOrderIDs = IDs.join(',');
    alert(AllOrderIDs);
    document.getElementById('hf1').value = AllOrderIDs;
}

function Check()
{
    var AllOrderIDs = document.getElementById('hf1').value;
    alert(AllOrderIDs);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" id="hf1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" onclick="Select(this, 1);" />
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" onclick="Select(this, 2);" />
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" onclick="Select(this, 3);" />
<br />
<p> <input type="button" onclick="Check();" value="Check" /> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting error messgage like object doesn't support this method or property..at  IDs.push(OrderID);

Comment: then you're probably doing something wrong. Make sure that AllOrderIDs is a string, not number. Don't convert it to Number.

Comment: well, it should. There is a file there - example.html. Do you see it?

Comment: i've modified my post, so that it includes a full source code listing.

Answer (score 1):

You missed this after alert:-

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_PagePlaceholder_hdSelectAllOrderId').value= AllOrderIDs
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed that line:

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_PagePlaceholder_hdSelectAllOrderId').value = AllOrderIDs;
```

By the way, don't refer to controls like that. Do this:

```
document.getElementById('<%=hdSelectAllOrderId.ClientID%>').value = AllOrderIDs;
```

Comment: if i select two checkboxes its working fine, when i select third one its showing like "NaN, 123" what is that NaN

Comment: That's because you can't convert "1,2" to number. Why do you convert to number?

Comment: I am not converting..I am just assigning to Hdnfield value..What if i use label instead of hiddenfield

Comment: This is converting: Number(document.getElementById('ctl00_PagePlaceholder_hdSelectAllOrderId').value)

Comment: once i select the checkbox, after that if i want to unselect how to remove the ordid with comma..

Comment: Try a different approach. Hold a global array of ids and deal only with it. At the end of the method just populate the array to the hidden field as a string but don't convert it back.